# getting file count in php codeigniter not working

Tags: php, file, codeigniter, directory, codeigniter-3

I am trying to get a count of files inside a folder in my CodeIgniter project, I did the following:

```
<?php
$fi = new FilesystemIterator(base_url().'uploads', FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
printf("There were %d Files", iterator_count($fi));
?>
```

but this gives me the following error:

> FilesystemIterator::__construct(http://localhost/drive/uploads):
> failed to open dir: not implemented

can anyone please tell me what is wrong in here, thanks in advance

Comment: error says, you do not have the `uploads` directory. Make sure the path is right and the directory is available with read permission.

Comment: @BhaumikPandhi i have folder named uploads inside my project drive

Comment: Have you tried using a _path_ instead of a _url_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it using ****DIR**** attribute in php and then giving the path inside a variable

```
<?php
$upOne = realpath(__DIR__ . '/../../../uploads');
$fi = new FilesystemIterator($upOne, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
printf("There were %d Files", iterator_count($fi));
?>
```